# Save bytearray image from Android to AWS S3 via sailsjs

Tags: android, arrays, node.js, image-uploading, multipart

I am trying to upload a gallery image in Android to S3 in multipart format. For that, I am sending an image from Android to nodejs (sails) in bytearray format and want to save that image to S3. I am doing it using the following code:

```
exports.galleryImageUploader = function(imageCodes, folderName, imageName, callback) {
  //imageCodes is the bytearray received from the client
  var bodyStream = fs.createReadStream(imageCodes);
  s3.putObject({
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: 'Images/Profile/' + folderName + '/' + imageName + ".jpg",
      ContentType: 'image/jpg',
      ACL: 'public-read',
      Body: imageCodes
  }, function(err, data) {
      if(err){
        return callback(err);
      }else{
      }
  });
},
```

But image is not getting properly saved on S3. When I open the image on my bucket, it shows a message that this file can not be opened because it contains error. Need help in solving this.

Comment: Download that image and compare with original. Tell us the differences.

Comment: And you should post your android code of course.

Comment: `from Android to nodejs (sails) in bytearray format and want to save that image to S3.`. Pretty unclear what this is about. So your Android device sends data to a node.js server. And then this node.js server forwards it to S3? How would that go?

Comment: @greenapps yes, android device converts a jpeg image to bytearray and sends it across the nodeJS server. Now using the AWS-SDK, I want to save this image to S3. But I am not clear about how to do this. Shall I first reconstruct the bytearray to the JPEG image and then save the JPEG image to S3, or shall I send the bytearray itself to S3. Can there be any better way?

Comment: `But I am not clear about how to do this.`. You did not answer my question. So there are two servers somewhere on the internet? A node.js server and an S3 server. And the node.js server forwards data to thst S3 server? Why so complicated?

Comment: `reconstruct the bytearray to the JPEG image`. You mean 'reconstruct the byte array to the jpg file'? If you put a jpg file in a byte array then there is nothing to reconstruct as the bytes in the array are the same as in the file. Just save the bytes to file.

Comment: @greenapps Ok, the flow is, that I have android device from which I pick up a gallery image and android converts it to byte array and sends it to nodejs (sails) server running on an AWS EC2 instance. On this instance I am able to receive the bytearray. And then there is an AWS S3 instance too running. This S3 instance is well connected to my EC2 instance through the nodejs server by using aws-sdk package installed on EC2. All the keys and bucket name variable are in place. For this bytearray problem, my only question is how do I save the received bytearray as an JEPG image on the S3?

Comment: You are talking a lot of all kind of things i have never heard of. And the strange thing is that you are not denying my concept of two servers somewhere on the internet. It now seems that there is only one server with some applications running where to exchange data?

Comment: `save the received bytearray as an JEPG image on the S3`. I do not understand the question. Nor the problem.  Just send the bytes of the bytes array unchanged to S3. Then S3 should save the bytes unchanged to file.

Comment: `from which I pick up a gallery image and android converts it to byte array`. This is already wrong. You get an uri to a file if you pick an image from gallery. Not an image.  You should just put the bytes of the file in a byte array. No conversion needed. The length of the byte array will be the length of the file.